# Wamp server not showing localhost\website

Tags: php, wampserver

I am trying to connect to wampserver. I have all setting done and wampserver is online. but when I try to connect to the folder then the url of site is loading as **http://website** instead of **http://localhost:8899/website**. because of this i am getting website not found error. How can I solve this?

Comment: Please try `http://localhost/website/`

Comment: what is the result of 127.0.0.1 ? port number 8899 is not the default one. did you changed it?

Comment: yes. I changed it and now it is online.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have an .htaccess in that folder or maybe your site is configured to redirect you to http://website, you should check the .htaccess or the site configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

Every project you add to your main folder will open this way if you try to open via WAMP's panel in `http://localhost/` , unfortunately.
I think this can be configured, but I don't know how to do so.

You can type the address manually as `http://localhost/website`. This should work.

Another solution is to make aliases, that'd work.